# Must Cordova app webview take full screen?

Tags: cordova

A Cordova application as I know it takes full screen of the app. Is there a way to make hybrid UI, I mean some element of the UI is from native code such that the webview doesn't take full screen or when a native UI element lays ontop of the webview in the view stack?

Comment: Do you tried with the option "<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />"?

Comment: @Exos: I want it NOT to be full screen, but it says that preference is fullscreen by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't have to be full size, you can embed the cordova webview on a native project and make it the size you want. And you can mix native parts with the cordova webview.

Take a look into the doc about embedding webviews
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_webviews_index.md.html#Embedding%20WebViews

There is another way if you wan't the app to be like a regular cordova project where you can add the plugins with the CLI, you can create a cordova project with the CLI and edit the native code to size the view or change other things. Here you have a two part tutorial about this for iOS:

http://devgirl.org/2014/07/22/mixing-cordova-phonegap-components-with-nativ/

http://devgirl.org/2014/07/24/mixing-cordovaphonegap-components-with-native-ios-part-2/

Comment: I read the iOS instructions because it's the only platform I'm familiar with. The instructions look like manually setting up a Cordova project on an existing non-cordova project. Is that what it is? And after the instructions it is essentially a Cordova project and I can use the standard Cordova command line tools to add plugins?

Comment: I think the CLI doesn't recognize the project as a cordova one and you have to use plugman to install the plugins instead, but I've edited the answer to add an example about creating a cordova app and editing the cordova webview

Comment: A very nice tutorial. Too bad it's not CLI friendly. I guess this is as good as it goes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The two part tutorial is CLI friendly, in fact, it creates a regular cordova CLI project to start the tutorial, and then customize the native views and the cordova webview

Comment: Oh?! It uses commands I am not familiar with. I use `cordova create`, `cordova build`, and add plugins by `cordova plugin add`. The page uses `plugman` as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Exos : `<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />`

And, if you would like to hide the navigation bar, you need Java Code in your **CordovaApp.java** (res) example for android :

```
import android.view.View;

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
  if(hasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

In your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: I want it NOT to be full screen. But it says the preference is false by default? I mean say I want the browser view to take only half of the screen?

Comment: Half resolution or half screen ? Pleaz push an another ask. It's different.

Comment: It's the same question. Half a screen, not half resolution. My title "Must Cordova app webview take full screen?" It means I don't want it to be full screen.

Comment: To be certain, I have a video recording screen that's presented in native UI. And I want it to share the same screen as the web UI.